# PHP - Variable inside a loop and another one outside

Tags: php, variables, loops

as the title said, i've this block of code and i want to know if i can write a variable that takes the name of another one similar to it but outside the loop.

is that makes a problem ?!

```
<?php 
   $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
   $subjects_set = mysql_query($query);
   errors_of($subjects_set);

    while ($db_subjects_rows = mysql_fetch_array($subjects_set)){
           echo "<li>{$db_subjects_rows["menu_name"]}</li>";

           $pages_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE subject_id = {$db_subjects_rows["id"]}");


        errors_of($pages_set);
        echo "<ul class=\"pages\">";
        while ($db_pages_rows = mysql_fetch_array($pages_set)){
        echo "<li>{$db_pages_rows["menu_name"]}</li>";
        }
            echo "</ul>";                       
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can access all variables that were declared outside of the loop inside it

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Using local variables inside a loop does not create a problem, if thats what you are asking, you should read about variable scopes

The function has a scope, the class has a scope and there is a global scope

Comment: A.Shabaan but what i'm asking for the variable inside the loop. the similarity between it and the one outside could make an error if i use the outside one in a function for example ?!

Comment: What is the name of the variable you are talking about ?

Comment: i think i get it permanently.
but if u donn mind i've another question :)
i've this function that i want to pass a value on it "function get_all_subjects ($all_subjects){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
  $subjects_set = mysql_query($query);
  errors_of($subjects_set);
 }" 
and when i recall it in the page this error appear  
"Notice: Undefined variable: all_subjects in C:\wamp\www\test_of_test\content.php" 
although that in the content.php page i put the function as it get_all_subjects($all_subjects);
why its undefined ?!

Comment: The variables inside the function are read only inside the function to change the value of the variable passed in the global scope you should pass it by reference, hence function get_all_subjects(& $all_subjects){// do some coding}

Comment: i sent you a message on your web page please find it out and send me back :)

Answer (score 0):

All the variables that is used `outside` the loop can be accessed `inside` the loop.Refer this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to know more about the PHP Variable Scope.